# Google Cloud: Mark OAuth Key as private

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I created an OAuth 2.0-Client-ID (Credentials) for a private application. The usage terms says that "OAuth Application Verification" is not necessary if I don't share my application. But if I open the "OAuth consent screen" in the cloude console it says "verification needed". The key seems to work anyway.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark your application as internal from the GCP console.

This [section](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#mark-internal) of the verification FAQ has more info on how to mark your app as internal.